# How can I do efficient range searching + counting with latitude/longitude data?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geography

I'm working with a large set of points represented by latitude/longitude pairs (the points are not necessarily unique, there could be several points in the set that are at the same location). The points are stored in a database.

What I need to do is figure out a way to efficiently perform a search to get the number of points that lie within a given radius (say, 25 miles) of an arbitrary point.
The count does not need to be 100% accurate - more importantly, it just has to be fast, and reasonably close to the correct count. Doing this with SQL is possible, by using a query with some trigonometry in the WHERE clause to filter points by their distance to a reference point. Unfortunately, this query is very, very expensive and caching is not likely to provide much help because the locations will be very spread out.

I'm ultimately looking to build some kind of in-memory structure that will be able to handle this kind of operation efficiently - trading off some of the accuracy and liveness of the data (maybe rebuilding it only once a day) in return for speed. I've been doing some research on kd-trees, but i'm not clear yet on how well this can be applied to latitude/longitude data (as opposed to x,y data in a 2d plane).

If anybody has any ideas or solutions I should look into, I'd really appreciate it - so thanks in advance.

Comment: Would help if you gave more info on the platform you'll be doing this in...

Comment: [This is to short to be a real answer] If you wanted to use a k-d tree, you would need to translate your cartesian-distance query into a latitude and longitude range (or, just do the math to see if a splitting latitude/longitude plane intersects your query).

Answer (score 9):

***I don't think you should use this solution. Having randomly thought about it a few days ago, I think that measuring the distance from a specific point the grid squares' locations will be based on circles rather than a uniformed grid. The further away from 0,0 you are the less accurate this will be!***

What I did was to have 2 additional values on my PostalCode class.  Whenever I update the Long/Lat on a PostalCode I calculate an X,Y distance from Long 0, Lat 0.

```
public static class MathExtender
{
    public static double GetDistanceBetweenPoints(double sourceLatitude, double sourceLongitude, double destLatitude, double destLongitude)
    {
        double theta = sourceLongitude - destLongitude;
        double distance =
            Math.Sin(DegToRad(sourceLatitude))
            * Math.Sin(DegToRad(destLatitude))
            + Math.Cos(DegToRad(sourceLatitude))
            * Math.Cos(DegToRad(destLatitude))
            * Math.Cos(DegToRad(theta));
        distance = Math.Acos(distance);
        distance = RadToDeg(distance);
        distance = distance * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (distance);
    }


    public static double DegToRad(double degrees)
    {
        return (degrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    public static double RadToDeg(double radians)
    {
        return (radians / Math.PI * 180.0);
    }
}
```

Then I update my class like so:

```
private void CalculateGridReference()
{
    GridReferenceX = MathExtender.GetDistanceBetweenPoints(0, 0, 0, Longitude);
    GridReferenceY = MathExtender.GetDistanceBetweenPoints(0, 0, Latitude, 0);
}
```

So now I have an x,y grid distance (in miles) from grid reference 0,0 for each row in my DB.  If I want to find all places with 5 miles of a long/lat I would first get the X,Y grid reference (say 25,75) then I would search 20..30, 70..80 in the DB, and further filter the results in memory using

```
MathExtensder.GetDistanceBetweenPoints(candidate.Lat, candidate.Long, search.Lat, search.Long) < TheRadiusOfInterest
```

The in DB part is ultra fast, and the in-memory part works on a smaller set to make it ultra accurate.

Comment: Thanks, this is the clearest answer I have seen on this kind of question, most people basically advise you to get Oracle, MS SQL or dive into specialist datastructures while, for a LOT of purposes this is fast (faster than most solutions I have tried, commercial or free), easy to implement and works very well. It can be fine tuned easily to fit really probably all you can throw at it.

Comment: You shouldn't use this solution. It will measure the distance from a specific point, which means the grid squares will be based on circles rather than a uniformed grid. The further away from 0,0 you are the less accurate this will be!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`R-Trees`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

In Oracle, using Oracle Spatial, you can create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_spatial ON spatial_table (locations) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

that will create an `R-Tree` for you and search over it.

You may use any `Earth Model` you like: `WGS84`, `PZ-90` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use some kind of search tree for spatial data, e.g. a [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). More such data structures are referenced under "See also".

Answer (score 2):

This UDF (SQL Server) will get you the distance between two lat/lon points:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[zipDistance] (
    @Lat1 decimal(11, 6),
    @Lon1 decimal(11, 6),
    @Lat2 decimal(11, 6),
    @Lon2 decimal(11, 6)
)
RETURNS
    decimal(11, 6) AS
BEGIN

    IF @Lat1 = @Lat2 AND @Lon1 = @Lon2
        RETURN 0 /* same lat/long points, 0 distance = */

    DECLARE @x decimal(18,13)
    SET @x = 0.0

    /* degrees -> radians */
    SET @Lat1 = @Lat1 * PI() / 180
    SET @Lon1 = @Lon1 * PI() / 180
    SET @Lat2 = @Lat2 * PI() / 180
    SET @Lon2 = @Lon2 * PI() / 180

    /* accurate to +/- 30 feet */
    SET @x = Sin(@Lat1) * Sin(@Lat2) + Cos(@Lat1) * Cos(@Lat2) * Cos(@Lon2 - @Lon1)
    IF 1 = @x
        RETURN 0

    DECLARE @EarthRad decimal(5,1)
    SET @EarthRad = 3963.1

    RETURN @EarthRadius * (-1 * ATAN(@x / SQRT(1 - @x * @x)) + PI() / 2)

END
```

And, obviously, you can use this in a separate query, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [dbo].[zipDistance] < 25.0
```

Comment: Just realized you did not want SQL? It should be easy enough to convert this to some other syntax. Counterpoint is that, depending on use, this works decent for me in my applications.

Comment: but still a good example of my proposal to store the sines and cosines rather than lat/longs.  Doing that you can reduce this function to just one trig function per row instead of five - that one being the last cosine term that's dependent on point1 *and* point2.

Comment: Interesting. Somehow I'll have to look into that. It may help me with this one huge database I have that collates data in zip areas...

Answer (score 2):

You can find an excellent explaination of Bombe's suggestion in the Jan Philip Matuschek's article "[Finding Points Within a Distance of a Latitude/Longitude Using Bounding Coordinates](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates)".

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe supply a sample of your existing expensive query?

If you're doing proper great-circle calculation based on taking the sine() and cosine() of the reference point and the other data points, then a very substantial optimisation could be made by actually storing those sin/cos values in the database in addition to the lat/long values.

Alternatively, just use your database to extract a rectangle of lat/long ranges that match, and only afterwards filter out the ones that are outside the true circular radius.

But do bear in mind that one degree of longitude is a somewhat shorter distance at high latitudes than at the equator.  It should be easy to figure out the right aspect ratio for that rectangle, though.  You'd also have errors if you need to consider areas very close to the poles, as a rectanglar selection wouldn't cope with a circle that overlapped a pole.