# Blackberry cache reverse geocode address info with proximity

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gps, reverse-geocoding, proximity

Most people are limited to about 5 or 6 locations on a daily basis (work, home, school, store, etc).  I want to speed up address display by caching a few of these most visited locations.  I've been able to get the address info using both google maps GPS and JSON and Locator.reverseGeocode.  What would be the best way to cache this information and to check proximity quickly? I found [this GPS distance calculation example](http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.java.html) and have it working.  Is there a faster way to check for proximity?

Answer (score 0):

Please see similar question first: [Optimization of a distance calculation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615206/optimization-of-a-distance-calculation-function)

There are several things we can change in distance calculations to improve performance:

1. Measure device speed and decrease or increase period of proximity test accordingly
2. Trigonometric calculations takes most of performence, but it may done much faster. First make bold distance calculations using [lookup table method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Computing_sines), then if distance is less than proximity limit + uncertainty limit, use [CORDIC method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC#Software_implementation) for more precise calculation.
3. Use constants for Math.PI/180.0 and 180.0/Math.PI

several links that may be helpful:
Very useful [explanations of CORDIC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9523/references-with-explanations-of-how-works-cordic-algorithm-for-division), especially [doc from Parallax for dummies](http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php?127241-CORDIC-for-dummies)
[Fast transcendent / trigonometric functions for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523531/fast-transcendent-trigonometric-functions-for-java)
[Cordic.java](http://www.soc.tuwien.ac.at/trac/jop/browser/java/target/src/common/com/jopdesign/sys/Cordic.java?rev=95206986d58d8958f34a6e9b4196fc9e74106576) at Trac by Thomas B. Preusser
[Cordic.java](http://code.google.com/p/seng440/source/browse/trunk/src/Cordic.java?r=6) at seng440 proj
[Sin/Cos look-up table source](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Sin/Cos_look-up_table) at processing.org by toxi