# Whats the most efficient way to calculate local users from a geo coord?

Tags: php, geolocation

[edit] - as pointed out to me in the comments I should have noted that I will be using a LAMP based architecture, meaning a MySQL database. Sorry about forgetting to mention this.

I have to create a PHP backend for an iPhone app. The app sends up the users coords and requests the closes 10 local users.

I'm just wondering what is the most efficient way to determine this, I dont want to have to scan the entire table of users, calculate the distance between their geo-coords and the target & order them from lowest to farthest.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution instead of scanning all the users? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You didn't wrote about which database you're using. Some support this out of the box and some support it with extensions.

Comment: Binary space partitioning may help you limit the search field.

Comment: I'll be using MySQL, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: [GIS and Spatial Extensions with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html); [Geo Distance Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bucket the users by approximate latitude and longitude (e.g. by whole degrees, or tenths of degrees, or whatever scale is appropriate to the distribution you've got) and then work outward from the querying user's bucket.

Not sure the extra complexity is worth it, though, unless the brute force approach is really a performance hog.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516574/how-can-i-do-efficient-range-searching-counting-with-latitude-longitude-data

Comment: thanks David, maybe I'm being too cautious, brute force might suffice for the amount of users Im expecting

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to use a spatial index or a space-filling-curve. A spatial index reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity thus it help subdivide the surface. You want to look for Nick's spatial index quadtree hilbert curve blog.

Comment: sounds complicated but I will look into it, thanks for your reply epitaph

Comment: You can download my hilbert curve class at phpclasses.org (hilbert-curve).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Here is one way to do it in a sql query.

```
$sql = "Select id, abs($currlat - latitude) + abs($currlon - longitude) as distance from geo_loc_table order by distance asc";
```

The issue with this is that it is not overly efficient. I would recommend getting some form of indexing software that can do the work for you. Sphinx might be a good fit.

Comment: To calculate the actual difference would be more complicated then that actually. I would recommend trying Sphinx anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Due to earth curve, you must do some calculation

```
SELECT id, 6371 * ACos(Cos(RADIANS(users.Lat)) * Cos(RADIANS(CurrentLat)) * Cos(RADIANS(CurrentLng) - RADIANS(users.Lng)) + Sin(RADIANS(users.Lat)) * Sin(RADIANS(CurrentLat)) ) AS distance
FROM users
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

`distance` is in Km, if you want Miles, replace 6371 by 3959